# How to get Cities from Geo Data

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, geospatial

I have some data about automobiles(particularly Transport Trucks). The Data includes Time , Latitude and Longitude of the vehicles among other things.

En Example Would Be:

```
Latitude        Longitude                       UTC
19.250463   73.042856           2018-12-01 00:02:19
19.249853   73.043862           2018-12-01 00:04:12
19.24953    73.043923           2018-12-01 00:04:41
19.249527   73.043938           2018-12-01 00:09:12
19.249457   73.044172           2018-12-01 00:14:12
19.249484   73.044128           2018-12-01 00:19:12
```

There is a lot of data. The problem i am facing right now is to find the various 'Cities visited by this certain vehicle.

Here is a plot of Latitude and Longitude:

[image]

Here I have added the number of points within a 20KM radius of each point as a feature in the data. Then I have applied DBSCAN on these three features and represented the classes as colors.

As you can see, It fails to recognize the 'Intersection' points. Ideally i need a way to find corners, endpoints in this data.

Having a predefined list of cities along with their locations is not an option, because the general are of these trucks can vary greatly and then can visit small towns as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you can solve this problem. The first, which would probably be the most performant, would be to build the inverse geocoding database yourself using information provided here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Of course this information would then have to be kept up to date which could be a pain.

If you're okay with a bit of latency, there are also third party services that do this for you. I run one of these third party services called https://geo-info.co/

You'd be able to solve this problem very easily with this API. For example

https://geo-info.co/19.250463,73.042856

Which would return the city along with some other info such as nearby locations.

```
{
    "city": "Vishnunagar",
    "community": "Kalyan",
    "community2": "",
    "country": "IN",
    "county": "Thane",
    "county2": "517",
    "latitude": "19.267",
    "longitude": "73.0715",
    "nearby": [
        {
            "city": "Dombivali I.A.",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.267",
            "longitude": "73.0715",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421203"
        },
        {
            "city": "Dombivali",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.2167",
            "longitude": "73.0833",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421201"
        },
        {
            "city": "Ramnagar (Thane)",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.2167",
            "longitude": "73.0833",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421201"
        },
        {
            "city": "Thakurli",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.2167",
            "longitude": "73.0833",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421201"
        },
        {
            "city": "Tilaknagar (Thane)",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.2167",
            "longitude": "73.0833",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421201"
        },
        {
            "city": "Bhiwandi",
            "community": "Bhiwandi",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.3002",
            "longitude": "73.0588",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421308"
        },
        {
            "city": "Khoni",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.3173",
            "longitude": "73.0597",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421204"
        },
        {
            "city": "Manpada",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.3173",
            "longitude": "73.0597",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421204"
        },
        {
            "city": "Nilje",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.3173",
            "longitude": "73.0597",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421204"
        },
        {
            "city": "Padle",
            "community": "Kalyan",
            "community2": "",
            "country": "IN",
            "county": "Thane",
            "county2": "517",
            "latitude": "19.3173",
            "longitude": "73.0597",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "state2": "16",
            "zipcode": "421204"
        }
    ],
    "state": "Maharashtra",
    "state2": "16",
    "zipcode": "421202"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The nearby feature seems to be especially useful for me. Though I was wondering if there was any way analyse this and get the endpoints in that graph?

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you mean by endpoints in that graph? I don't think I am following.